# $T$ automorphism of a finitely generated $A$-module, then $T^{-1} \in A[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. Let $T: M \to M$ be an isomorphism. Then $T^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $T$ with coefficients in $A$.

This seems to me as a direct application of proposition 2.4 in Atiyah-Macdonald, which says that $T$ satisfies an equation of the form $T^n+a_1T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$. Indeed, we just multiply by $T^{-1}$ and get the required identity.

However, I was told that a solution exists using integral extensions, to show that $T^{-1} \in A[T]$ by looking at $A \leq A[T] \leq A[T,T^{-1}]$ and using the correspondence of prime ideals between integral extensions (5.10 in Atiyah's book). This feels like an unrelated fact which I cannot utilize here.

So, is the 'easy proof' correct? And how can it be proven using the guidance?

Comment: How does multiplying by $T^{-1}$ help? It would work if $a_n$ is a unit.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I think Leullame's argument rather shows that $T$ is a polynomial in $T^{-1}$. But this can be applied to $T^{-1}$ instead of $T$, and we get the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your easy proof isn't quite right because $a_n$ might not be a unit.  However, you can multiply the equation by $T^{1-n}$ and get that $T$ is a polynomial in $T^{-1}$, and then swapping the roles of $T$ and $T^{-1}$ gives the desired result.

For the suggested proof, suppose $T^{-1}$ could not be expressed as a polynomial in $T$.  This means $T$ is not a unit in $A[T]$, so there is some prime $P\subset A[T]$ containing $T$.  By Proposition 2.4 applied to $T^{-1}$, $T^{-1}$ is integral over $A$, so $A[T,T^{-1}]$ is integral over $A[T]$.  Thus there exists a prime $Q\subset A[T,T^{-1}]$ such that $Q\cap A[T]=P$.  But since $T$ is a unit in $A[T,T^{-1}]$, no prime can contain $T$, so no such $Q$ can exist.

Comment: If you know that $T^{-1}$ is integral over $A$, then you already have the result by the OPs "easy" proof. It wouldn't make sense to use the big machinery that comes with integrality.

Comment: I agree, OP's proof is easier.  But OP asked for a proof in terms of the properties of prime ideals between integral extensions, and this is that proof.  And it seems rather likely to me that this is what whoever told them that such a proof exists had in mind.  After all, they were told to look at $A\leq A[T]\leq A[T,T^{-1}]$, so presumably they need to know that these extensions are integral.